# maps of enums and lambdas in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, enums

currently working on a small 3rd person game, I am facing some problems working with lambdas in maps. I want to map a function to a specific enum element.
To be specific: 
I have a keycode vector

```
std::vector<EKEY_CODE> _keys;
```

It holds elements given in an enum:

```
enum EKEY_CODE
{
    KEY_LBUTTON          = 0x01,  // Left mouse button
    KEY_RBUTTON          = 0x02,  // Right mouse button
// ...
}
```

For function calling, I have chosen to take a map:

```
using KeyMap = std::map<EKEY_CODE, std::function<void(const EKEY_CODE&, f32, f32)>>;
```

which is declared in the Game.h file:

```
KeyMap _keyActions;
```

The key vector is filled in the constructor:

```
Game::Game() : 
_keys({ KEY_KEY_W, KEY_KEY_A, 
KEY_KEY_S, KEY_KEY_D, KEY_KEY_C, KEY_LSHIFT, KEY_SPACE })
{
// ...
}
```

Now, I made a function to fill the key map:

```
void Game::fillMaps() {

auto move = [](const EKEY_CODE&, f32 movSpeed, f32 fdt) {
    // do funny things here
};

for (EKEY_CODE& key : _keys) {
    _keyActions.insert(key, move);
}
```

}

Now my problem is now that IntelliSense says "no instance of overloaded function std::map<_Kty, _Ty, _Pr, _Alloc>::insert [...] matches the argument list".
As I have seen it, I have given all parameters the right way for the lambda function. Is there anything I might not have seen in this? Shouldn't the insert function of the map be able to handle the lambda function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should get familiar with the tools you are using.  [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) is a list of all of the overloads for `insert`.  Do you see one that takes what you are giving it?

Comment: @taiBsu You likely meant to use `_keyActions.emplace(key, move);`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I fear I don't get your point here. 
@FrançoisAndrieux using emplace will make it work (thanks for that!), but I can't see why. As I know `insert` takes a copy of the function to the map while `emplace` constructs it there - but wouldn't giving a copy to the map work too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`_keyActions.insert({key, move});`

OR

```
_keyActions[key] =  move;
```

OR

```
_keyActions.insert(std::make_pair(key, move));
```

Or even better:

```
_keyActions.emplace(key, std::move(move));
```

Comment: okay, I guess now I get the problem. `insert` has to be given a pair to make the map know what key belongs to the value.

Comment: @taiBsu No, insert has to be given a pair simply because that is how they wrote the API.  It could have taken 2 values easily.

Comment: You forgot emplace